# Print an element array in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, laravel

I have a jquery function that calls a controller which in turn calls a function that I extracted the data from the users table. I return an array cin all the data in the table. ID, username etc etc.. So mold date in jQuery and indeed the array is full. Ex. [{"Id_user": "21", "username": "cassy1994"}].
From this array I have to extract only the username. How can I do?
This is the Ajax function:

```
$(".apprezzamenti").click(function()
{    
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var txt = "";

    $.get("http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/apprezzamenti/"+id, 
    function(data)
    {
        $(".modal-body-apprezzamenti>p").html(data);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: `data['username']` or `data[0]['username']` depending on how your `data` array is on return. Hint, try using `console.log(data)`

Comment: I use json_encode() in function of controller. So i use this code to print array: $(".modal-body-apprezzamenti>p").html(data); in paragraph. Executing this code print entire array but but i need only username. But i use this code: $(".modal-body-apprezzamenti>p").html(data['username'); does not print anything

Answer (score 0):

If the json is parsed, your object is stored in an array, so:

```
data[0].username
```

If not (if it is a string), you need to parse it first:

```
data_parsed = JSON.parse(data);
// data_parsed[0].username
```

Comment: The code works and I thank you.
One last thing. I have multiple users in the array. To print the username of all users as I do? I was wondering if you could help me out on how to use the loop.

Comment: jQuery has a nice each function which you can use... Try `$.each(data_parsed, function(index, value) { console.log(value.username) });`

Comment: Using console.log (value.username) does not print anything, but if I use only value.username print only a username

Answer (score 0):

assuming `data` is where your response is stored, `data[0].username` should work. Example:

```
$(".modal-body-apprezzamenti>p").html(data[0].username);
```

To print all usernames:

```
var count = 0;
$.each($(".modal-body-apprezzamenti>p"), function() {
    this.html(data[count].username);
    count++;
]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The code works and I thank you. I had to add only this "data_parsed = JSON.parse(data);". One last thing. I have multiple users in the array. To print the username of all users as I do? I was wondering if you could help me out on how to use the loop.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the problem. It's okay though, I realized that with this code I'm using can not seem to generate as many sections as there are users want to print and it shows me only the last username because it can generate only a paragraph in html. A possible solution which would it be?
This is the code:

```
$(".apprezzamenti").click(function()
{    
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var txt = "";

    $.get("http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/apprezzamenti/"+id, 
    function(data)
    { 
        data_parsed = JSON.parse(data);

        for(var i=0; i<data_parsed.length; i++)
        {
            $(".modal-body-apprezzamenti>p").html((data_parsed[i].username));     
        }       
    }); 
});
```